# toString() of Integer or Boolean without returning Object ID

Tags: java, object, tostring

I have a set of classes which represent digital logic gates, and I would like to create a toString() command which will recursively go through and print them.  The problem is that they can contain a Gate, Boolean, or Integer, and when I call Boolean.toString() or Integer.toString(), the Object ID is printed rather than the assigned value.  Is there a way to generically call a toString() (or similar) command on these objects and have them print the assigned value?

With the code below, the output looks something like: "AND([I@6ca1c,[Z@1bf216a)"

I would like it to look like: "AND(11,true)"

```
public static class Gate{
    public Object in1;
}

public static class ANDgate extends Gate{

    public Object in2;

    public ANDgate(Object first,Object second){
        in1 = first; // these can be Integer, Boolean, or another Gate
        in2 = second;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return("AND(" + in1 + "," + in2 + ")");
    }
}

public static class NOTgate extends Gate{

    public NOTgate(Object obj){
        in1 = obj; // this can be Integer, Boolean, or another Gate

    }
    public String toString(){
        return("NOT(" + in1 + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems this is not the hash value - looks like the JVMs object ID (hash value is an int). Btw. Integer.toString() does not return the hash, it returns the integer value in decimal format. Maybe you can provide an example how you use this method?

Comment: @home: My apologies, I'm still working on understanding all of the correct language in Java.  I've updated the question to be more accurate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your output clearly says that you pass `int[]` and `boolean[]` into your constructor, not `Integer` and `Boolean` as you say (see [`Class.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) for the meaning of binary type names such as `[I`).

If it's expected, than you need to provide your own function to convert arrays to `String` and use it instead on using the default `toString()` implementation that return hash-based values for arrays.

Comment: That's correct! `[Z@...` is what gets printed when you call `toString` on a `boolean[]`, and `[I@` shows up for `int[]`.

Comment: Thanks, you actually revealed another bug in my code!  I was intending to pass elements pulled from arrays, but I forgot to index them and sent the entire array, multiple times.

Comment: @DavidK: When I'd suggest to do it in more type-safe way: implement a special subclass of `Gate` that wraps a primitive value, and pass `Gate`s instead of `Object`s.